# The flat support of a module

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative ring and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module.

> What is known about the following subset of $ \mathrm {Spec}(R)$:
>
> $$\mathrm{supp}_{fl}(M)=\{P\in \mathrm {Spec}(R):\ \mathrm{Tor}^R_1(M, R/P)= 0\}?$$

In particular,

> Is $\mathrm{supp}_{fl}(M)$ open in $\mathrm {Spec}(R)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that Graham Denham's argument only shows that the weaker condition $\mathrm{Tor}_1(M,\kappa(P))=0$ is open, where $\kappa(P)$ is the residue field of $P$. With the problem as stated, here is a counterexample: for a field $k$, take $R=k[x,y]$ and $M=R/(x,y)$. Then it is easy to check that $\mathrm{supp}_{fl}(M)$ consists of:
$\bullet$ the generic point of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$,
$\bullet$ all closed points except the origin $(x,y)$, and
$\bullet$ all principal primes $(f)$ where $f$ is irreducible and not in $(x,y)$, i.e. all generic points of curves not containing the origin.

This is not open in $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

At least $\mathrm{supp}_{fl}(M)$ is open in $\mathrm{mSpec}(R)$.  To see this, let $(C_\cdot,d)$ be a resolution of $M$ by finitely-generated free modules.  By looking at matrices over $R$, one sees $\mathrm{Tor}^R_1(M,R/P)\neq0$ if and only if a maximal prime $P$ contains the (maximal) Fitting ideal of $d_1\oplus d_0$.

These closed sets are the homology jump loci of the complex $C_\cdot$, and the argument I sketch appears in

*Nero Budur*, MR 2875860 [**Complements and higher resonance varieties of hyperplane arrangements**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2875860), *Math. Res. Lett.* **18** (2011), no. 5, 859--873.

though it goes back further.